# How to make coordinate similar of two different array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two different arrays. I want to make them similar. For example

[image]

If difference between coordinates of two array is 1 then it will make it similar otherwise not.It would be nice If anybody help me out.

Comment: similar as in array2 will become array1?

Comment: There is no code present here.

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
A =
     1     5
     2     6
     3     7
     4     8
     5     9
     6     1
     7     2
```

and 
 B =

```
 2     6
 3     7
 4     8
 5     9
 7     1
 8     2
 7     5
```

`ismember()` will give you all the indices which have difference equal to 1
ismember(B-A,1)

ans =

```
 1     1
 1     1
 1     1
 1     1
 0     0
 0     1
 0     0
```

and then

```
>> B(ismember(B-A,1)) = A(ismember(B-A,1))

B =

     1     5
     2     6
     3     7
     4     8
     7     1
     8     1
     7     5
```

as you can see replaces all the values in B which have difference equal to 1 as B